# C++ - index of element in sorted std::vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, stl

I have an `std::vector` that I know is sorted. Using `std::binary_search` I can find whether an element is in the vector in log time. Unfortunately `std::binary_search` doesn't return the index of the element in the vector in case of success (or if it does I don't know how to access it). `std::find` will give me an iterator to the element but it doesn't use the fact that the vector is sorted so it runs in linear time and not log time. I know I can trivially implement my own binary search algorithm but I want to know if there is a way to do this in the standard.

Comment: [std::lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the lower_bound() function.  It's a little bit funky to make it generally useful, but serves the purpose you want.

Comment: See [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/) for an example of how `binary_search` can be implemented using `lower_bound()`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) (O(log(N)) and [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) (O(1) for random access iterators):

```
auto lower = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), val);
// check that value has been found
const bool found = lower != v.end() && *lower == val;
```

Then, either

```
auto idx = std::distance(v.begin(), lower);
```

or plain arithmetic:

```
auto idx = lower - v.begin();
```

Comment: You need to check whether `*lower` is `val` or not. You also need to check `lower!=end`.

Comment: @Nawaz Correct, added, since it is easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

Use `equal_range`, not `lower_bound`.

You can’t simply check if the iterator returned by `std::lower_bound` is different from the end to know whether the element is in the collection. If the element is not present, `std::lower_bound` returns the location where it should have been, not the end of the collection.

See: https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/01/16/how-to-stdfind-something-efficiently-with-the-stl/

Answer (score 0):

Tweaking the `std::binary_search` you can get :

```
template<typename Iter, typename T>
Iter my_find(Iter begin, Iter end, T value)
{

    Iter i = std::lower_bound(begin, end, value);

    if (i != end && *i == value)
        return i; // found in container
    else
        return end; // not found
}

auto it = my_find(v.begin(), v.end(), val); //it is your iterator
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this using lower_bound in STL c++:

// let the vector be v

```
int func(){
     int position = lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),element_to_be_searched) - v.begin();
     if(position == v.size()) // element not found
     {
         return -1;
     }
     else{
          return position;
     }
}
```